# Condition on "PropertyGroup" in Directory.build.props not working

Tags: msbuild

I've created a Directory.build.props file so I can set the C# language version in there.
But I also have Visual Basic Projects, so i wanted to limit the setting to C# projects.

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ProjectExt)'=='.csproj'">
        <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>   
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But my project is not loading it / the UI is not displaying the language version 7.2.
I've tried to apply the same condition inside the csproj file, also not working.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion Condition="'$(ProjectExt)'=='.csproj'">7.2</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, this will work:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="Condition working" Importance="high" Condition="'$(ProjectExt)'=='.csproj'"/>
</Target>
```

The build will output my message

Why is the condition not working on my LanguageVersion? Any Clues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to use a property to condition on that is available very early in the build. In your case, you should condition on `MSBuildProjectExtension`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.csproj'">7.2</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See [MSBuild reserved and well-known properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties) for the complete set of available properties.

`ProjectExt` is only defined late in the build definition and is therefore not available in `Directory.Build.props`, which is imported very early into the project.

Comment: In my particular case, the problem was that I was relying upon a `ProjectName` property. Switching to `MSBuildProjectName` fixed the problem.