# Directory.Build.props in root folder with c# and f# projects causes issue

Tags: c#, f#, msbuild

When creating a new Visual Studio solution, I would like to use `Directory.Build.props` to control the c# version number for all c# projects without having to set them individually.

However, having a mix of c# and f# folders causes a compilation error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0246  Unrecognized value '8.0' for --langversion use --langversion:? for complete list    FSharpLib   C:\source\solution\FSharpLib\FSC    1   Active
```

This is the smallest solution to demonstrate the issue.  In a real solution there is obviously more projects.

#### Folder Structure

\solution
\solution\Directory.Build.props
\solution\CSharpLib
\solution\FSharpLib

#### Directory.Build.props

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

#### Project Files (for completeness)

CSharpLib

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

FSharpLib

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Library.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Is it possible to have `c sharp` and `f sharp` projects side by side with a `Directory.Build.props` in the root folder to only apply to `c sharp` projects?

Moving the build props to a folder with only csharp projects beneath would work but I don't want to structure things this way - I want related modules alongside each other.

Comment: You might be able to condition the `LangVersion` based on the project's file extension. Unfortunately I don't recall the syntax off the top of my head and don't have a lot of time at the moment, so instead of an answer I'll direct you to the MSBuild docs: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019>.

Comment: I would much rather create a unit test that verifies that every C# project in the solution sets the language version to the desired value. If the language version is not set in the project, then the source is no longer unambiguous, and can't be moved to other solutions and be expected to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.csproj'"` to your `Directory.build.props` `PropertyGroup` to apply it only to C# projects.

Comment: This doesn't actually work in my testing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538024/344223) for the correct syntax.